# SetDefaultAccountValues in Account object it show sum error

Tags: triggers, apex-code

This is my code. I have to set the default value for `Account` fields like Name ,Phone etc...but it shows some error.

```
trigger setDefaultAccountValues on Account (before  insert, before update){


    for (Account acc : trigger.new){
        acc.Name ='xxx';
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Error: Compile Error: Variable is not visible: name at line 5 column 9
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What programming language is this? Apex?

Comment: ya it's an Apex programing language.

Comment: What are the access modifiers for the `Name` member in the `Account` class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is Apex, so check out this tutorial: [How to write a trigger in Apex](http://sfdcdownunder.blogspot.de/2009/02/how-to-write-trigger-in-apex.html).

**[UPDATE]**

Most probably you need to add the `public` (or `global`) [access modifier](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) to the `Name` (or `name`, since Apex is case insensitive) variable in the `Account` class.

Comment: `acc` is an object which instantiates the `Account` class. It's `name` variable should have the `public` access modifier to make it visible in your code.